# Title and Overflow menu in toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, overflow-menu

How can I add overflow menu without `setSupportActionBar`(toolbar) because when I'm doing like this overflow menu appears but then `toolbar.setTitle("");` does not work along with other toolbar methods, and I have to setTitle and other things using `getSupportActionBar();`

If we have to set all things via actionbar then what is the need of toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.yourmenu);
```

For menu item click use this:

```
toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener()
```

And dont `setSupportActionBar()`

Comment: what are the ways to implement the callback inside OnMenuItemClickListner, after all we can't toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener(new ...) in the onCreate(), would be not cleaner code

Comment: to do click events just do that **switch(item.getId()){
        case R.id.item:
          //Do stuff
        break;
}**

Comment: yeah but should I make separate class for the callback and pass reference to it or resort to inline callback? which is good way

Comment: For me the inline is the best, but you can use the way that you want.

Comment: What about the up button?

Comment: up button is a menu button?

Comment: No its navigation up button

Comment: like ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: Just set **toolbar.setNavigationIcon()** for navigationIcon and for click  **toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener()**.